# how to overcome IE bug when dynamically attaching div to body from script

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, dom, dhtml

UPDATE: the HTML was not well formed. This was causing the script to appear in inner div. Please ignore the question.

IE ver<8 has a known bug (Internet explorer cannot display the page. Operation aborted) 
If a script tries to append something to upper level block:

The bug is described [here](http://support.microsoft.com/?scid=kb;en-us;927917&x=9&y=18):

Update: I rephrased the question and simplified the example:

The bug occurs in the following code:

```
[end of html file]
<script type="text/javascript" >
if (window.document.body){
    var c_div = window.document.createElement('div');
    window.document.body.appendChild(c_div);    
}
</script>

</body>
```

Question: This seems to me exactly similar to example1 Method1 In Microsoft workaround ([here is the link again](http://support.microsoft.com/?scid=kb;en-us;927917&x=9&y=18)). How come I still have the bug? What am I missing here?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Run your code in a domready/onload event handler.

Comment: Please read the update. According to Microsoft it should work without onload event. See above.

Comment: wouldn't make sense to change the dom before it is ready anyway

Answer (score 0):

It might be a slightly insane approach but could you pull out the innerHTML of the entire `<body>` append your string to it and then set the `<body>` innerHTML to the new value?

May affect some previously attached JS events unless it's inline onclick stuff.

Answer (score 0):

The HTML in the page was not well formed. Please ignore the question.