# $.each makes IE crawl

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer

I am trying to use JSON to populate a div, so I basically run a loop to go through the entire data I get, about 200 records and fill it into a div.

It work great in most browsers, but IE it crawls to the core. Is there some solution to the problem?

Thank you for your time.

Comment: Do you have an example of the JSON data and your usage of $.each()?

Comment: Which version of IE? The different versions have different speeds, ranging from "snail" to "tortoise".

Comment: Can we see the code? You may want to built the whole string and throw it at innerhtml.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Are you adding each bit of data to the div at a time? Each addition makes the browser have to call a redraw, which you could save by concatenating and adding it all at the end.

```
function doStuff(json) {
    $.each(json,function(key, val) {
       $('#myEl').append(val); //redraws every time.
    });
}

function doStuffBetter(json) {
    var html = '';
    $.each(json,function(key, val) {
       html += val;
    });
    $('#myEl').append(html); //only 1 redraw
}
```

Comment: can you show us the code? or link to the site? We're stabbing in the dark here.

Comment: found this question which might help solve your needs.  doesn't decrease time, but doesn't lock the browser while doing so: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/788614/ways-to-increase-performance-when-set-big-value-to-innerhtml

Answer (score 0):

Last week I watched [a Google Code talk about JavaScript optimization](http://google-code-updates.blogspot.com/2009/06/nicholas-c-zakas-speed-up-your.html). There was a good discussion about looping, and I think I remember that $.each was slow. Not sure it'll help, but you may want to watch the video.

Comment: It would certainly be useful to build the same code using a for loop and see how significant the difference is.