# Create a range or html fragment in IE from a string

Tags: javascript, dom, dhtml

How do I take a string and create an html fragment with it in IE.  This works fine in non-ie browsers.

```
var str = "<div>Foo</div>";
var range = document.createRange();
var frag = range.createContextualFragment(str);
var e = document.getElementById("element");
e.appendChild(frag);
```

Comment: `createContextualFragment` is not at all necessary considering the widespread adoption of `innerHTML`. Here are a couple answers that use document fragments to avoid the dangling extra div you'd get with a straight `innerHTML` approach: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/814564/inserting-html-elements-with-javascript/814649#814649 and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/788614/ways-to-increase-performance-when-set-big-value-to-innerhtml/788661#788661

Comment: innerHTML has quite a few idiosyncracies across the major browsers.  I'd really like to know how to do this using w3c compliant code.

Answer (score 1):

You may want to consider using jQuery? Cross-browser compatible and far easier to use:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var str = "<div>Foo</div>";
  $('#element').append(str); //assuming your element's id is 'element'
});
```

[jQuery site](http://jquery.com/) and [documentation](http://docs.jquery.com/Main_Page)