# Parsing HTML element attributes from string (RegExp)

Tags: javascript, html, regex

I just need to get all attributes and text from given string via RegExp, if it's possible with one line RegExp would be wonderful. I want to get each attr from string if it is in " or ' or standalone.

- Attr: `value = "1" or value = '1' or value="1" or value='1' or value=1 or value=""`
- Attr: `readonly or disabled`

I tried, this but not works for me.

```
var s = '<option value="1" data-foo="Foo" readonly>Value 1</option>', m
m = s.match(/<option ([^>]*)>(.*)<\/option>/)
console.log(m)
// gives ["<option value="1" data-...adonly>Value 1</option>", "value="1" data-foo="Foo" readonly", "Value 1"]
```

Thanks a lot.

Comment: I'm not sure what you need it for, but would it work for you to try a selector like `document.querySelector("option[value='1'][data-foo='Foo'][readonly]").outerHTML`?

Comment: I need, if str has any attr, get all attrs from str or null.

Comment: I guess I didnt get what your input & desired output is.

Comment: why not `s.split(" ")`? Just curious if it could work

Comment: No split, cos attrVal can contain space.

Comment: Ah, right. Like `classname = "cls1 cls2"`. I kind of assumed it wouldn't. And what about using something similair, but excluding splits that have a (opening)quote-something-(closing)quote? I.e., split with a regexp that excludes single/double quotes? I dont believe that there are unquoted attribute values with spaces

Comment: -1 instead of explaining your actual needs in the answer, you should explain them in the question...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually I was needing this for handling "option" elements with a more simple way, more simple regexp. Cos of ie doesn't not append if use `innerHTML = append content` for `select` elements.  Append operation is mentioned at links below, but does not work for option elements. And than I find a solution for this problem. If append content is option or options than use `handleOptionElements`, if not use `asyncInnerHTML`.

```
function append(el, child) {
    if (child.nodeType === 1 || child.nodeType === 3) {
        // Without clone, removes element if it is copied from document
        return el.appendChild(child.cloneNode(true));
    }

    content = trim(content);
    if (content.substring(0, 7) === "<option" && 
            content.substring(content.length - 7) === "option>") {
        handleOptionElements(content, el);
    } else {
        el.innerHTML = content;
    }

    return el;
}
```

http://james.padolsey.com/javascript/asynchronous-innerhtml/
[Ways to increase performance when set big value to innerHTML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/788614/ways-to-increase-performance-when-set-big-value-to-innerhtml/788661)

```
var re_standaloneAttributes = /^(select|disabl)ed$/i,
    re_optionSearch = /<option\s*([^>]*)>(.*?)<\/option>/gi,
    re_attributeSearch = /([^\s]*)=["'](.*?)["']|([\w\-]+)/g;

function handleOptionElements(content, targetElement) {
    var options = [], attributes = [],
         optionElement, optionElements = [], createOption;

    (""+ content).replace(re_optionSearch, function(src1, attr, text) {
        if (!src1) return;
        (""+ attr).replace(re_attributeSearch, function(src2, name, value) {
            if (!src2) return;
            name = name || src2;
            value = value || (value = re_standaloneAttributes.test(name) ? name : "");
            attributes.push({name: name, value: value});
        });
        options.push({text: text || "", attributes: attributes});
        // Reset attributes for each element
        attributes = [];
    });

    createOption = (function() {
        var option = document.createElement("option");
        return function() { return option.cloneNode(true) };
    })();

    forEach(options, function(option) {
        optionElement = createOption();
        // optionElement.text doesn't work on ie 7-8
        optionElement.textContent = optionElement.innerText = option.text;
        forEach(option.attributes, function(attribute) {
            optionElement.setAttribute(attribute.name, attribute.value);
        });

        if (targetElement !== undefined) {
            targetElement.appendChild(optionElement);
        } else {
            optionElements.push(optionElement);
        }
    });

    return optionElements;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Why not just create the element?

```
var s = '<option value="1" data-foo="Foo" readonly>Value 1</option>'​​​​​;

var test_element = document.createElement('div');
test_element.innerHTML = s;

var element = test_element.childNodes[0];
​var attributes = element.attributes;

for (var i = 0; i < attributes.length; i++) {
    var attribute = attributes[i];

    console.log(attribute.name, '=>', attribute.value);
}​
```

Output:

```
value => 1
data-foo => Foo
readonly =>
```

**Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/mcRc4/**

Comment: I guess the OP wants to check if the attribute value is specified in quotes or without.

Comment: @techfoobar: I dunno, the question is a little vague. I though that OP was just looking to extract the attributes of an element from a string.

Comment: Looking at it again, i'm confused too. If all the OP wants is getting the values, regex parsing is definitely not required or advised.

Comment: It does not work in ie7, cos `test_element.childNodes[0]` is nodeType=3 (textNode) for it, but ff say nodeType=1

Comment: @qeremy: How about `childNodes[1]`?

Answer (score 0):

The following regex i believe fetches what you want (well, looks ugly for sure but)

`s.match(/<option\s*([^\s\=]*)\s*\=*\s*([^\s\=]*)*\s*([^\s\=]*)\s*\=*\s*([^\s\=]*)*\s*([^\s\=]*)\s*\=*\s*([^\s\=]*)*>(.*)<\/option>/);`

For `s = '<option value="1" data-foo="Foo" readonly>Value 1</option>'`, it returns:

```
[
  "<option value="1" data-foo="Foo" readonly>Value 1</option>", // s itlsef
  "value", // first attr
  ""1"", // value as written in s (with double quotes)
  "data-foo", // second attr
  ""Foo"", // value as written in s (with double quotes)
  "readonly", // third attr
  undefined, // no value specified for readonly, so undefined
  "Value 1" // the option text
]
```

Comment: Thank but this is not useful for it, cos option could have not attr or more than 3.