# Long html binding freeze browser

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, knockout.js

I'm using `KnockoutJs` html attribute binding to render a big html document (~2 mega) into a `DIV` element like this:

```
<div id="myDiv" data-bind="with: $root.myDocument">
     <div id="elementBody"  data-bind="html: body">
     </div>
</div>
```

it works great but binding time takes about 3-4 seconds while user browser freezes becoming unusable.

Is there a way to render this document avoiding this long binding time? Can I render it progressively?

#### What I tryied

I tryied with this custom binding but it not seems to be a solution:

```
ko.bindingHandlers.appendText = {
    init: function (element, valueAccessor, allBindings) {
    
        var data = ko.utils.unwrapObservable(valueAccessor());
   
        var array = data.match(/.{1,1000}/g);
  
        $.each(array, function (i, val) {
            setTimeout(function () {
                $(element).append(array[i]);
            }, 5);
        });
    }
};
```

It breaks tags and the document is not visible till the `.each` loop ends.

Comment: I don't think you can improve much on calling `element.innerHTML = data;` directly. Although you might want to have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/788614/ways-to-increase-performance-when-set-big-value-to-innerhtml

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In principle, your setTimeout technique DOES help to give the DOM time to render the contents in between adding badges of HTML. However, your binding is not written correctly to leverage this:

```
    $.each(array, function (i, val) {
        setTimeout(function () {
            $(element).append(array[i]);
        }, 5);
    });
```

What this does, it 'synchronously' loops over all the array items, and adds the different setTimeout calls all at the same time. What you probably want to do instead, is to do the first append, then setTimeout to do the second append, then setTimeout to do the 3rd append, etc.

```
// replacing your foreach loop
var $element = $(element),
    appendItem = function (index) {
        if (index < array.length) {
            $(element).append(array[index]);
            setTimeout(function () {
                appendItem(++index);
            }, 1);
        });
    };
appendItem(0);
```

This should trigger the rendering in between adding badges (haven't tested the code, so sorry if there's mistakes in it). However, this will probably make the whole process go even slower if you measure it from start till end, because there will (possibly) be a BUNCH of DOM redraws now. You can give it a try though.

The real question is, what CAN you expect? 2 MBs of DOM content is A LOT. I wonder how fast you could ultimately get it.

One additional tip that might or might not improve rendering time: while using the fix I proposed, set the element that uses the custom binding to `display: none` while rendering. The fix should help keep the dom (sort of) responsive, but most browsers will optimize away DOM reflows when the element that is changing is not displayed. If this works, you can negate the extra performance penalty of batched appending that I mentioned earlier.

Comment: If the operator ++ appears before the variable, the value is modified before the expression is evaluated. If the operator appears after the variable, the value is modified after the expression is evaluated.

So in your script you have to do: appendItem(++index) otherwise index is going to be always 0.